# What is an 'independent parameter' of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I saw the following question a book of mine:

> Show that an $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix has $n(n-1)/2$ independent parameters.

I have no idea what an *independent parameter* is. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: $Q$ is orthogonal if its transpose is equal to its inverse:
$Q^T=Q^{-1}$.

Comment: I know that @zoli, but I'm asking about the *'independent parameter'* term.

Comment: sir, since we have the requirement that our matrix has to be orthogonal, we are not completely free to choose its "parameters", the numbers belonging to the indices $i,j$....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ Bernard , you did not show the algebraic independence of the $n(n+1)/2$ relations. For instance, if $U$ is a fixed square matrix, the commutativity relation $UX-XU=0$ gives $n^2$ relations between the entries ; yet the previous relations are not independent. In fact, generically, there are $n^2-n$ independent relations. More generally, if $X$ satisfies a matrix equation $f(X)=0$ the number of independent relations between the entries is given by the rank of $Df(X)$, the derivative of $f$ in $X$. Here $f(X)=A^TA-I$ and $Df(X):H\rightarrow H^TA+A^TH$. Note that $Df(X)=0$ iff $A^TH\in \mathcal{K}$, the set of skew symmetric matrices. Then $Df(X)(H)=0$  iff $H\in A^{-T}\mathcal{K}$. Since $A$ is invertible the vector space $ A^{-T}\mathcal{K}$ has the dimension of $\mathcal{K}$, that is $n(n-1)/2$ and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

It means that an $n\times n$ matrix is just an element of $\mathbf R^{n^2}$ since it has $n^2$ coefficients $a_{ij}$, which are considered as *parameters*. These parameters are, informally, independent since you can choose any of them as you please, whatever the other coefficients are.

In the vector space (of dimension $n^2$) of all matrices, it asserts the orthogonal matrices
satisfy $\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$ (quadratic) independent relations, hence a number of independent coefficients equal to $$n^2-\frac{n(n+1)}2=\frac{n(n-1)}2.$$

These relations result from $A\,^{\mathrm t}\! A=I$: as the product of these matrices is symmetric, it is enough to write:
$$\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}a_{kj}=\delta_{ik},\quad 1\le i\le k\le n.$$
There are as many relations as pairs $(i,k)$ satisfying the above relationsinequalities.